# How to create custom derived class of logic_error in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'd like to create my own errors off the logic error from stdexcept. I tried the following and am facing errors, my guess is, its not the proper way of doing it. I was not able to find answers on google or previous stack overflow questions, pardon my noob-ness.

```
// Header
class My_custom_exception : public logic_error
{
public:
    My_custom_exception(string message);
}
// Implementation
My_custom_exception::My_custom_exception(string message)
{
    logic_error(message);
}
```

I do not know how to do the implementation. It gives me following errors:

```
exception.cpp: In constructor ‘My_custom_exception::My_custom_exception(std::__cxx11::string)’:
exception.cpp:3:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::logic_error::logic_error()’
 My_custom_exception::My_custom_exception(string message)
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:128:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const std::logic_error&)
     logic_error(const logic_error&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:128:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:120:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const string&)
     logic_error(const string& __arg);
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:120:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
exception.cpp:5:21: error: declaration of ‘std::logic_error message’ shadows a parameter
  logic_error(message);
                     ^
exception.cpp:5:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::logic_error::logic_error()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:128:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const std::logic_error&)
     logic_error(const logic_error&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:128:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:120:5: note: candidate: std::logic_error::logic_error(const string&)
     logic_error(const string& __arg);
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:120:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call the constructor of the base class(es) in the initializer list of your class' constructor.
Like this:

```
My_custom_exception::My_custom_exception(string message):
    logic_error(message)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use the base class constructor in initializer list of you constructor:

```
My_custom_exception::My_custom_exception(string message)
    : logic_error(message){};
```

Or inherit constructor from the base class (since C++11):

```
class My_custom_exception : public std::logic_error {
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};
```